# Chrome extensions: where did gradual release feature go to?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

On Google Developer dashboard for chrome extensions, there used to be a checkbox to enable "gradual release" when editing an extension. You could then pick a number (for example: 5%) and this enabled you as an extension developer to first push a new version only to a select amount of users in order to "feel the pulse" before publishing the extension to everyone.

I have just notices that this feature no longer exists in developer dashboard. Did Google decide to cancel it or something like that, or am I missing it somehow? Anyone knows why they took it out?

Comment: Was it ever there? I don't remember that, and I've been using it for years. Maybe it's only enabled for high-user-count extensions, though.

Comment: Yup. I have used it for several times with several of my extensions, and now the feature is gone for all of them without notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the Chrome team and have been informed that your extension needs to have more than 10K users for this feature to be made available.